# Two async module functions work asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I tried to scrap for thousands of pages. So I used async.timesSeries and async.waterfall. Each of functions work synchronously very well but they don't work together. What can I do?

The logic is simple.

1. Because I want to scrape pages are "http://udb.kr/local/category/390101?page="1~1167, async.timesSeries loop 1 to 1167
2. async.waterfall scraps components of pages

but messages that console shows me looks like this

```
info.NM values // just for explain, It shows me each attires of obj because I insert console.log(info.NM) for verifying.
info.NM values
info.NM values
info.NM values and randomly ----- page number -----
...
['done',
'done',
'done',
'done',
'done',
...
'done']
info.NM values again

.../Users/Snark/Dev/job_apply/cheerio_job_app_list.js:29
            if (tObj[m+1].children != 0) {info.nAddr = tObj[m+1].firstChild.data}else{info.nAddr = null};
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
    at /Users/Snark/Dev/job_apply/cheerio_job_app_list.js:29:17
    at fn (/Users/Snark/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1212:16
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:166:37
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:706:43
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /Users/Snark/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1208:30
    at Request._callback (/Users/Snark/Dev/job_apply/cheerio_job_app_list.js:21:6)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/Snark/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
```

And this is js code.

```js
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    jsonfile = require("jsonfile"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    async = require("async");

var info = {},
    dbArray = [];

var url = "http://udb.kr/local/category/390101?page=";

async.timesSeries(1166, function(n, next) {
    var page = n + 1
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            request(url + page, function(error, response, html) {
                if (error) {
                    throw error
                };
                var $ = cheerio.load(html),
                    tObj = $('tbody tr td');
                callback(null, tObj);
            });
        },
        function(tObj, callback) {

            for (var m = 0; m < 150; m = m + 5) {
                if (tObj[m]) {
                    info.NM = tObj[m].firstChild.children[0].data
                } else {
                    info.NM = null
                };
                if (tObj[m + 1].children != 0) {
                    info.nAddr = tObj[m + 1].firstChild.data
                } else {
                    info.nAddr = null
                };
                console.log(info.NM);
                dbArray.push(info);
            }
            callback(dbArray, callback);
        },
        function(dbArray, callback) {
            fs.appendFile('./jobDB_l.json', JSON.stringify(dbArray), function (err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
            });
            callback(null, 'done');
        }
    ], function(err, result) {
        console.log('----- ' +page+ '-----');
    });
    next(null, 'done');
}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get these to work together where you are using waterfall inside of each timesSeries iteration, you need to call the timesSeries `done` callback from the completion callback for the waterfall call.  Right now, you are calling it long before that which means that timesSeries won't wait for the waterfall to be done.

You can do that by changing this:

```
], function(err, result) {
    console.log('----- ' +page+ '-----');
});
next(null, 'done');
```

to this:

```
], function(err, result) {
    console.log('----- ' +page+ '-----');
    next(null, 'done');
});
```

---

It also seems odd that you have a hard-coded `for` loop limit of `m < 150` rather than using the actual length of the content.  You can easily run off the end of the content and potentially cause problems.

And, your error handling probably won't work well either.  If you `throw` inside of the async `request()` callback, that's not going to go anywhere.  You need much better error handling such as calling `callback(error)` to pass the error on to `async.waterfall()`.

You also may want to surround all your DOM walking in a try/catch so if you throw any exceptions there, you can catch them yourself, analyze them and then fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tObj[m+1] && tObj[m+1].children != 0)
```

Comment: /Users/Snark/Dev/job_apply/cheerio_job_app_list.js:18
   if(error){throw error};
             ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND udb.kr udb.kr:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)

still.. another error

Comment: I'm sorry, it's very hard to help when you ask a question seemingly about async behaviour, post an exception, and when I solve that exception, then you post another error, that has nothing to do with the original question. This one looks like a DNS problem or something like that, but if so then I'm pretty sure it wouldn't work in sync mode either.